# Distance metric for algorithms

Tags: algorithm, distance, theory

I am currently working on a project in which I need to quantify the (dis)similarity between algorithms - that is, I have a few tens of algorithms that are used for the same purpose and I would like to quantify which ones are closest (i.e., more similar) to others, and which are truly 'novel'.

Both my Google-Fu and my SO-Jutsu have failed me, so I would appreciate if anyone could shed a light on this. Does such a metric even exist?

Comment: Google-Fu and SO-Jitsu haha. If only we could upvote questions based on their use of puns.

Comment: Does classifying them preliminary on absolute metrics such as run time and memory complexity show that similar algorithms appear close by?

Comment: In Genetic Programming there is the notion of evolving programs by small mutations -- and usually where there is a notion of small mutations then there is a notion of distance, so it might be worthwhile to look into some of the research in genetic programming (although that is about *programs* rather than *algorithms*). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming

Comment: Thanks everyone. I intend on using runtime and memory complexity as a secondary line of evidence to validate any inferences I may make based on the distance (whatever that may be) between the algorithms.

@JohnColeman, the idea of borrowing ideas from GP is an interesting one. Since I'll be expressing all algorithms in terms of a common framework / standardised implementation first, it may be possible to use some concepts from GP. It's a long shot, but it's a start.

Answer (score 2):

As one measure of similarity, you could create `n` datasets, somewhat intelligently constructed, and then run each of your algorithms on all of these datasets. You then get an `n`-dimensional vector of runtimes associated with each algorithm, which you can then slap any old distance on. I'd imagine something like cosine distance would be a good first guess, since if your datasets are of various sizes you would sort of be classifying your algorithms by the way that they scale. In addition to runtimes, you could monitor maximum memory usage or whatever else you can think of measuring.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in another comment, I intend on using runtime and memory complexity as a secondary line of evidence to validate any inferences I may make based on the distance (whatever that may be) between the algorithms.